# Help in understanding the demonstration of Seifert's Theorem (about Hopf Vector Field)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm reading the book "The dynamics of vector fields in dimension 3" - "Matthias Moreno and Siddhartha Bhattacharya". On page 10 the authors define

> **Hopf flow on $\mathbb{S}^3$:** We identify $\mathbb{S}^3\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ with $\{ (z_1,z_2):|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 1\}$, and we define the flow $\phi$ on $\mathbb{S}^3$ by $$\phi^t(z_1,z_2)= (e^{2i\pi t} z_1 , e^{2i\pi t} z_2). $$

The author doesn't write this in the book, but I think that the Hopf vector field is $H: \mathbb{S}^3 \to T \mathbb{S}^3$; $H(a+ib,c + id) = ( (a+ib, c+ id) , 2\pi(-b + i a ,-d + ic)$.

After this, the book does the following procedure (sorry for the big image).

[image]

My problem is in the demonstration of the Lemma 1, I really don't understand what he did.

> **My Doubts about the Lemma's demonstration:**
> **1)** I think in the underlined part in blue is $\pi^{-1} (C)$ instead
> of $C$ (because doesn't make sense an orbit of $X_i$ lies in $C$).
>
> **2)** The underlined red part doesn't make much sense to me, how
> these $h$'s are taken? Which periodic orbits were used to construct
> those Poincare's first return map?
>
> **3)**  And finally, about the green
> underlined text, anyone knows where can I find a demonstration of this
> property?

---

Can anyone help me to understand this demonstration or propose another reference to I see the demonstration of this theorem (Seifert's Theorem)?